# Kernel module compile against overwritten dependencies

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-modules

So, I have installed a driver/kernel module for a wifi module from Laird. It works well but I noticed that it also install a kernel module named cfg80211 which is overwrite the existing kernel module. So the laird instalation updated and overwrite the original cg80211 kernel module. I can see this new cfg80211 kernel modules in updates folder inside /lib/module/{uname -a}.

The problem is, now I want to install another wifi USB dongle kernel module. This wifi USB dongle kernel module also depend on cfg80211 kernel module. I compiled it against the original kernel source. It compiled okay but it cannot load because the cfg80211 that are loaded in the kernal is different version, which is the updated kernel module from laird than it compile against.

Is there any method to solve this?

What I can think of is to compile with the updated cfg80211 instead of the original from linux kernel source. Is there a way to do this?

Another thing is to unload the new cfg80211 and reload the original cfg80211 kernel module although this will make the laird kernel module will fail to load. Is there any way to do this too?